# Find string enclosed in brackets

Tags: performance, go

I have this find function. Is it concise, efficient and readable with good logic flow?

```
// findFirstStringInBracket finds the first string enclosed in brackets.
func findFirstStringInBracket(str string) string {
    if len(str) > 0 {
        indexFirstBracketFound := strings.Index(str, "(")
        if indexFirstBracketFound >= 0 {
            runes := []rune(str)
            wordsAfterFirstBracket := string(runes[indexFirstBracketFound:len(str)])
            indexClosingBracketFound := strings.Index(wordsAfterFirstBracket, ")")
            if indexClosingBracketFound >= 0 {
                runes := []rune(wordsAfterFirstBracket)
                return string(runes[1 : indexClosingBracketFound-1])
            } else {
                return ""
            }
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    } else {
        return ""
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You took something simple and made it complicated. Keep it simple and readable.

```
func findFirstStringInBrackets(s string) string {
    i := strings.IndexByte(s, '(')
    if i < 0 {
        return ""
    }
    i++
    j := strings.IndexByte(s[i:], ')')
    if j < 0 {
        return ""
    }
    return s[i : i+j]
}
```